# How can I make Eclipse work with `perlbrew`?

Tags: eclipse, perl, perlbrew

I'm using `perlbrew` to switch between perl versions. I also use Eclipse to write perl scripts.

It seems that Eclipse does not recognize the switches between perl versions, and keeps working with the base version installed out of `perlbrew`. I tried restarting Eclipse but this doen't help.

So, How can I make Eclipse work with `perlbrew`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EPIC, this will work: Click through to Window->Preferences->Perl EPIC and set the Perl executable to `perl5/perlbrew/bin/perl`. This always points to the current set version of perl. The path is relative to your $HOME on Linux.

Comment: There is no such symlink in os x installation, either 0.41 or 0.58.  So I had to specify the perl I wanted.  A slight pain, but not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this as I usually just use a text editor for Perl, but I have taken to using the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env perl` so that I get the `perl` for the user that runs the script (ie. perlbrew if me, system perl if root). If Eclipse executes the script (`./myscript.pl) this should work, if instead it calls`perl myscript.pl` then this will not help you.